# Why is there a syntax error with this eval?

Tags: perl, syntax-error, eval

I'm just trying eval for the first time, and get a compilation error for the following piece of code:

```
my $dom;
eval {
    $dom = $PRSR->load_xml(location => $fullpathname, no_blanks => 1);
}

my $dtlDocType = getObjectType($dom); # <----- the error occurs here
```

It says "Global symbol $dtlDocType requires explicit package name". When I remove the eval and let the line setting $dom stay without a block, it works. Initializing $dom in the first line to anything doesn't make any difference.

What is the problem?

Comment: `eval { ... }` needs a semi-colon after it, it is not a block.

Comment: Oh... thanks. Would never have thought of that.

Comment: You're welcome. The documentation seems to refer to it as a block, not quite sure why, when it does not have this characteristic of a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval { ... }` needs a semi-colon after it.

Comment: Thanks! The docs say specifically "eval BLOCK", so I kind of went blind to the semicolons in the examples that follow ...

Comment: 'eval BLOCK' is an expression, yes. To put it in a statement you need to suffix it with a semicolon.